# RecyclerView Item Click Not Navigating to Fragment in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am currently creating an inventory management system for an android application using Kotlin within Android Studio. As part of this I want my users to be able to see a **list of products** **(fragment_list.xml/ListFragment.kt)** and when they select a specific product it will bring them to a **Product Page with more details** **(fragment_product_details.xml/ProductDetailsFragment.kt)**. The code that I currently have for this looks correct however when I click on a product nothing happens. I have logged the product click as well as the instantiation of the new fragment however nothing happens, it stays on the list of products. Please see below code

**Fragment_List.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ListFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.finalyearproject

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.finalyearproject.databinding.FragmentListBinding

class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setUpRecyclerView()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        val context = requireContext()
        val db = DataBaseHandler(context)
        val products = db.readData()

        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(products) { product ->
            // Handle item click here
            // For example, navigate to a new fragment to display more information about the clicked product
            val fragment = ProductDetailsFragment.newInstance(product)
            val transaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
    }
}
```

**fragment_product_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductDetailsFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etvProductName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:text="Product Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etvProductDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etvProductName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:text="Product Description" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**ProductDetailsFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.finalyearproject

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.finalyearproject.databinding.FragmentProductDetailsBinding

class ProductDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentProductDetailsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentProductDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Retrieve the product object from arguments bundle
        val product = arguments?.getParcelable<Product>("product")

        // Use the product object to display details if not null
        product?.let {
            // Display product details
            binding.etvProductName.text = it.brand
            binding.etvProductDescription.text = it.description
            // Display other details as needed
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        // Companion object function to create a new instance of the fragment
        fun newInstance(product: Product): ProductDetailsFragment {
            val fragment = ProductDetailsFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putParcelable("product", product)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**recycler_view_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.finalyearproject

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val products: List<Product>, private val onItemClick: (Product) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = products[position]
        holder.itemName.text = product.brand
        holder.itemDescription.text = product.description

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RecyclerViewAdapter", "Item clicked: ${product.brand}")
            onItemClick(product)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return products.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val itemName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name)
        val itemDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_description)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:background="#FF9800"

        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleTextColor="#000000" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.finalyearproject
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupWithNavController
import com.example.finalyearproject.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Create variables to allow us manipulate the navController and ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
//    val db = DataBaseHandler(this)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Force lightmode
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

        //Inflate Activity
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Set up Navigation Controller for the Bottom Navigation Bar
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.activity_main_nav_host_fragment)
        setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView, navController)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

    }
}
```

**Product.kt**

```
package com.example.finalyearproject

import java.util.Date
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class Product(
    var barcode: Long = 0,
    var brand: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var note: String = "",
    var quantity: Int = 0,
    var category: String = "",
    var date: Date? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Finally, this is the output of the log when I click the "Stabilo" product from the list. As you can see it is registering the click as well as the instantiation of the new fragment however nothing is showing up

```
Item clicked: Stabilo
newInstance called
```

Comment: Your code is using a `NavHostFragment`, which means you should not be using any FragmentTransactions at all. Is there a reason you aren't [navigating to a destination in your graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/navigate) or using [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/safe-args) to pass data between screens?